# Request all rows and handle them with JS or use ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, database

I'm building a web app in which users have a page where they can see statistics about their results.  They can decide to see certain results according to 3 choices they make using a `<select>` (let's say : date, object used, technique used).  When they change any of the 3 `<select>` values, the graph of results needs to be updated dynamically to show results that match these 3 values. Total number of results per user should not exceed 10 000 and a result line in DB contains 19 columns. Should I...

1. Make one DB request to get all results that match the user ID and then handle them with javascript.
2. Make a new ajax call every time the user changes any `<select>` value

I think the second option is better since the first option could imply that my JS script manages a very big array with more than 50 000 elements in it... Or am I wrong?

Comment: sounds correct, 50,000 elements would probably be a heavy array to handle

Comment: @klikas Thank you!